# How to redirect (Rack) Thin server output to console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, thin

Thin server has -l option to redirect output to log file (default: log/thin.log). Is there a way like in webrick server the output is always to console (and log/development.log) too ?

Comment: On Sinatra, use `enable :logging`.

Answer (score 3):

My installed version of Thin automatically outputs to the console. If yours doesn't, you could try updating your installed version.

You could also try `thin -l -`, which tells Thin to redirect output to STDOUT.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using rails, add this to your gemfile:

```
gem 'thin', :group => 'development'
```

And then from the console, use:

```
rails s
```

This will send logs to standard out and to log/development.log

Don't use "thin start", as some of the docs say.

Answer (score 0):

Mine does automatically output into console however if I use a Procfile, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I use  `thin start -d` to start thin as a background daemon with default logging and send the output of the file back to console with

> tail -f log/thin.log

This way the server doesn't stop if terminal closes, but I can see output from `puts` statements. If you want more detailed logging from thin that's a bit different.

To stop the service/daemon use `thin stop`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add a small code snippet in your config.ru file, and thin output all app logs to the console, without having to `tail` the log file and it keeps the log coloring intact

Details here: Thin server: [Thin server: ouput rails application logs to console, as 'rails s' does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158675)