# Thin server: ouput rails application logs to console, as 'rails s' does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I need to run `thin start` or `thin -ssl ... start` within the root of my rails app, and see the application logs output to the console, similar to what `rails s` does

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In `config.ru` file, located at the root of your application, add the following code, just before the line `run Rails.application`:

```
console = ActiveSupport::Logger.new($stdout)
console.formatter = Rails.logger.formatter
console.level = Rails.logger.level

Rails.logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(console))
```

Comment: But this is going to affect all environments, and most likely pollute the production machine logs. I am using thin in development because it's faster than Webbrick, is it possible to target only this environment ?

Comment: Simply wrap the above code in a `if Rails.env.development?` block

Comment: @Benj This is the most marvelous answer ever provided on SO. I never thought that was possible. Now I have the colorful debug output using `thin`, thank you vey much.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `config/environments/development.rb` file is configured to print logs, in case it is not, you can add these lines there and do not forget to restart the rails server.

```rb
logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
```